# date range date picker restriction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Three issues

- restrict the date like this user choosing end date base on the start date onwards only (sample:1/1/2015-12/31/2014 which is wrong)
- the user unable to manually type in a date
- have the calendar start at today's date

HTML

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2"> Date</div>
            <div class="span7 input-append input-prepend">
                <input type="text" id="sdate" name="sdate" value="<?=$sdate?>" class="input-small" ><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;to</span>
                <input type="text" id="edate" name="edate" value="<?=$edate?>" class="input-small" ><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#sdate, #edate').datepicker();
    //$.loadData();  

    $('a.btn').unbind('click').bind('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.loadData();

    });
```

Comment: </script> </script> is not correct syntax.

Comment: sorry typo error. thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 0):

This can all be very easily achieved using jquery `datepicker` function.

```
    <input type='text' id='t1' readonly/>
```

And the Jquery:

```
$('#t1').datepicker({
    minDate: 'today'
});
```

Keeping the input field readonly will no allow the user to manually enter the date. Also, keeping the `minDate` to either `today` or `0` will restrict the user from selecting invalid range and set the min date to today. Read up **[jquery datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)**

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pygx3snv/2/)